# Descent for admissible representations of algebraic groups over local fields

Tags: automorphic-forms, langlands-program

Let $G$ be a reductive group and $F$ be a local field which is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Assume $\Pi$ is an irreducible smooth admissible representation of $G(F)$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_l$, where $l$ could be $p$. Can $\Pi$ always descend to a representation of $G(F)$ over a local field contained in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_l$?
The motivation of the question is a similar question in Galois side: [Does the image of a p-adic Galois representation always lie in a finite extension?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17774/does-the-image-of-a-p-adic-galois-representation-always-lie-in-a-finite-extensio) and the $p$-adic Langlands program where we consider admissible unitary representations on a Banach space over a local field over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.